# How do I handle entry management in a map of lock objects?

Tags: kotlin, concurrency, locking, semaphore, concurrenthashmap

My application creates an index which is saved in thousands of files on the disk. I want to access the index files with multiple instances of the application. Therefore I use the java FileLock to lock the files I am reading between the different JVMs.
If I try to acquire a FileLock twice with the same application, I get an `OverlappingFileLockException` (that is how FileLock is supposed to work). To prevent multiple acquires on the same file within one instance, I create a Map. If the app can acquire the semaphore for the specific file, it can also acquire a FileLock. If not, the file is currently in use by the application.
With a `ConcurrentHashMap`, it works like a charm. I use `computeIfAbsent` to add Semaphores to the map if needed.

The problem is: The more files I create, the more semaphores I store in the map. Running the application for several days can cause the map to explode. To prevent this, I want to remove unused entries, when they are released.

I can't just remove the semaphore like in the 2nd version of the function. If the Semaphore has queued Threads, the next thread in the queue will acquire the FileLock. A new thread won't find the semaphore in the map and will create a new one, acquiring the FileLock again. I have to check if `semaphore.hasQueuedThreads()` and only remove it, if there is no queued thread. But this is not an atomic operation.
I tried to lock the acquire/release functions for the Semaphore with a single semaphore to make both functions synchronized (bad practice), just to see if it could work. This ended in a deadlock.

```
val lockMap = ConcurrentHashMap<String, Semaphore>()

fun accessFile(fileName: String) {
    acquireSemaphore(fileName: String)
    acquireFileLock(fileName: String)
    doSomethingWithFile(fileName: String)
    releaseFileLock(fileName: String)
    releaseSemaphore(fileName: String)
}

fun acquireSemaphore(fileName: String) {
    (lockMap.computeIfAbsent(fileName){Semaphore(1, true)}).acquire()
}

fun releaseSemaphore(fileName: String) {
    lockMap[fileName]?.release()                // works, but the map keeps every semaphore
}

fun releaseSemaphore(fileName: String) {
    lockMap.remove(filename)?.release()     // removes the semaphore, but causes OverlappingFileLockExceptions
}
```

I want to remove a semaphore from the map when it is released and there are no threads waiting for the semaphore. This should be an atomic operation so no 2nd semaphore is created for the same file.

Comment: Let's take a step back a bit. Basically, your problem is that your semaphore (I question your use of semaphore. You probably want a regular lock) per `FileLock` solution doesn't scale memory-wise. A question you might want to ask yourself is do you really need one lock per `FileLock` or can you live with some `FileLocks` sharing a lock, reducing the memory footprint. If so, you might want to take a look at striped locks.

Comment: I have multiple instances of my application and each application uses multiple threads to access the files. I need a per-file lock mechanism to prevent concurrency issues and data corruption. Files are intended to be very small and access time very short. The number of applications and threads is unknown and can vary. I can't benefit from shared locks (like locking parts of the file with `FileLock`) because due to the small sizes I always access the whole file. Sharing read locks might work out for reads, but don't solve my problem for concurrent writes.